# How to deal with serialization - Campaign Monitor API

Tags: php, serialization, http-post

I am using Campaign Monitor API to send emails. The API allows to create a templated email  through a method called create_from_template(). As [the doc says](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/campaigns/), I need to add some formatted parameters. Here's what the campaign monitor create_from_template() method implements:

```
/**
     * Creates a new campaign from a template based on the info provided.
     * At least on of the ListIDs and Segments parameters must be provided
     * @param string $client_id The client to create the campaign for
     * @param array $campaign_info The campaign information to use during creation.
     *     This array should be of the form
     *     array(
     *         'Subject' => string required The campaign subject
     *         'Name' => string required The campaign name
     *         'FromName' => string required The From name for the campaign
     *         'FromEmail' => string required The From address for the campaign
     *         'ReplyTo' => string required The Reply-To address for the campaign
     *         'ListIDs' => array<string> optional An array of list ids to send the campaign to
     *         'SegmentIDs' => array<string> optional An array of segment ids to send the campaign to
     *         'TemplateID' => string required The ID of the template to use
     *         'TemplateContent' => array required The content which will be used to fill the editable areas of the template
     *     )
     * @access public
     * @return CS_REST_Wrapper_Result A successful response will be the ID of the newly created campaign
     */
    function create_from_template($client_id, $campaign_info)
    {
        return $this->post_request($this->_base_route . 'campaigns/' . $client_id . '/fromtemplate.json', $campaign_info);
    }
```

thus I gave as $campaign_info parameter

```
        $list = array($list_id);
        $data = array(
            'Name' => $name_string,
            'Subject' => $subject_string,
            'FromName' => $some_name,
            'FromEmail' => "contact@email.org",
            'ReplyTo' => "contact@email.org",
            'ListIDs' => $list_id,
            'SegmentIDs' => array(),
            'TemplateID' => 'a6dd1168417a6d7d7f94da70c3cafe15'
            'TemplateContent' => array(
                                       'Singlelines' => array('Content' => $a_string ,
                                                              'Href' =>  $a_href
                                                              ),
                                        'Multilines' => array('Content' => $content
                                                             ),
                                        'Images' => array('Content' => $some_url,
                                                          'Href' => $some_href,
                                                         )

                                      )
                  );
```

But when launching my api post request to campaign's monitor server, I keep on having a message :

```
object(CS_REST_Wrapper_Result)#32 (2) { ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (2) { ["Code"]=> int(400) ["Message"]=> string(110) "Failed to deserialize your request. Please check the documentation and try again. Fields in error: campaign" } ["http_status_code"]=> int(400) }
```

Does anybody knows where it could come from ?

Edit: If I pass these parameters

```
$template_content = array(
  'Singlelines' => array(),
  'Multilines' => array(),
  'Images' => array(),
  'Repeaters' => array()
);
```

and then in the array `$data` `'TemplateContent' => $template_content`, everything works fine, but when I add some parameters, it won't work

Comment: It seems the request is supposed to be json encoded. Have you tried wrapping the array in json_encode() before passing it to the create_from_template method?

Comment: @ChrisHanson, See my edit, it seems it can understand the array formatting

Comment: @ChrisHanson : In fact i manage to do that using for 'TemplateContent' entries nested arrays  => array(array('Content'=> $content,..)),

Answer (score 3):

G'day user1611830,

As per the [sample in the github repo](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/blob/master/samples/campaign/create_from_template.php), each of Singlelines, Multilines, and Images needs to be an `array` of `arrays`.

And it would be best to include an empty `array` for Repeaters.

So you're probably looking for something like this (apologies if i'm missing any parentheses, but as long as you wrap each of Singlelines, Multilines, and Images in another `array()` you should be right:

```
$template_content = array(
    'Singlelines' => array(
        array(
            'Content' => $a_string,
            'Href' =>  $a_href
        )
    ),
    'Multilines' => array(
        array('Content' => $content)
     ),
    'Images' => array(
        array(
            'Content' => $some_url,
            'Href' => $some_href,
        )
    ),
    'Repeaters' => array()
);
```